How do I read all of Rick Riordan’s books in Chronological order?
I know there’s already one for this, and it’s this link (In what order should Rick Riordan's mythological series be read to make the most sense, and what is the chronological order?) I think, but this is from 2 years and 11 months ago, and I was wondering how I would read them as of September 2024? I’ll mainly be using this, but I’d like to know where Sun and the Star, the Chalice of the Gods, and alike/suck fall into place. I’m assuming CotG falls after HoO, maybe even ToA, still wondering about SatS though.

This question is still a duplicate of In what order should Rick Riordan's mythological series be read to make the most sense, and what is the chronological order?. We don't want to have new posts on the same topic every few years. If you like, I can "bounty" the older question, essentially offering my reputation to attract updated answers

Bounty added to older Q.
